# JQuery Rotate isn't working correctly in winforms WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, winforms

I have a small web page with a dynamic timer on it that I made using JQuery Rotate.

It works great in chrome, firefox, and IE.  The problem is, I wrote it to work inside of the WebBrowser control of a winforms app.

[image]

When viewed through a winforms app, the Z-layering doesn't work correctly, and the spinning images seem to actually resize as they spin causing them to change position under the overlays.

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a way to still do this control in win-forms without resorting to making a bunch of images and just removing sections to "animate" it.  It has to have dynamic timing, so I can't make it a gif.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#f').fadeTo(0, 0.6);


        var OrigSecs = getParameterByName('Seconds');

        if (OrigSecs == null || OrigSecs == '') {
            OrigSecs = 10;
        }

        OriginalMS = OrigSecs * 1000;

        Start = +new Date();

        setInterval('rotate();', Interval);
    });

    var OriginalMS = 0;
    var Interval = 20;
    var Start;


    function rotate() {


        var End = +new Date();

        var CurrentMS = End - Start;

        var rotation = CurrentMS / OriginalMS * 360;

        if (rotation < 361) {
            $('#e').rotate(rotation);
            if (rotation <= 180) {
                $('#c').rotate(rotation);
            }
        }

        if (rotation >= 180) {
            $('#c').hide();
            $('#e').css('z-index', 3);
            if (rotation >= 360) {
                $('#e').hide();
            }
        }

    }


    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:209px;width:209px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;">
        <img id="a" src="Images/Lock.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;" />
        <img id="b" src="Images/WhiteBot.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" />
        <img id="c" src="Images/BlueBot.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:3;" />
        <img id="d" src="Images/WhiteTop.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:2px;left:0;z-index:4;" />
        <img id="e" src="Images/BlueTop.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:5;" />
        <img id="f" src="Images/LockOverlay.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:6;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can think of only three ways to fix this:

1. Find a winforms control that can mimic this web page I've made EXACTLY
2. Fix the javascript in some way so that it doesn't screw up in the winforms browser
3. Find a way to make the browser compatible with my web page

Can anyone point me to one of these solutions?

Comment: can you set a fiddle that reproduces the wrong behaviour?

Comment: Yes and no... the fiddle would show the correct behavior in all browsers, you would have to actually have the web page I wrote and run it in a .NET forms application to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of tinkering with it, I figured out a solution.  By placing the misbehaving images inside their own div tags, then performing the same z-index switches on them it works correctly in the WebBrowser control:

HTML Change:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:209px;width:209px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;">
        <img id="a" src="Images/Lock.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;" />
        <img id="b" src="Images/WhiteBot.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" />
        <div style="height:208px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:3;overflow:hidden;">
            <img id="c" src="Images/BlueBot.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:3;" />
        </div>
        <img id="d" src="Images/WhiteTop.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:2px;left:0;z-index:4;" />
        <div id="e2" style="height:208px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:5;overflow:hidden;">
            <img id="e" src="Images/BlueTop.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:5;" />
        </div>
        <img id="f" src="Images/LockOverlay.png" height="208px" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:6;" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript Change:

```
if (rotation >= 180) {
            $('#c').hide();
            $('#e').css('z-index', 3);
            $('#e2').css('z-index', 3);
            if (rotation >= 360) {
                $('#e').hide();
            }
        }
```